# find index of dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to be able to identify which dynamically added checkbox was clicked (either by index or name or whatever). Here is a fiddle I found on a similiar question: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vABvy/)

I want it to display like "This is the 3rd checkbox" instead of just "clicked". Is that even possible?

I've tried `$(this).index()` but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you can use `index()` to get the index of the current element within a matched set. From that you can use a helper function to format the ordinal number to show. Try this:

```
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function (e) {
    alert('This is the ' + getOrdinal($(this).index('[type=checkbox]') + 1) + ' checkbox');
});

function getOrdinal(n) {
    var s = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"],
        v = n % 100;
    return n + (s[(v - 20) % 10] || s[v] || s[0]);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vABvy/138/)

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I wanted. I'll accept answer as soon as it's possible =)

Answer (score 1):

Well, Rory made it faster. Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ae500393/1/) for it :)

HTML

```
<button id="append">Append</button>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<span></span>
```

JS

```
var checkbox = $('<input/>', {type : 'checkbox'});

$('#append').click(function(){
    $('.wrapper').append(checkbox.clone()).append('checkbox');
});

$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
    $('span').text('Index: ' + $(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
var checkbox = '<label><input type="checkbox" />Checkbox</label>';
$(document).on('click', '.add', function () {
    $('#group').append(checkbox);
    $('[type=checkbox]').checkboxradio().trigger('create');
    $('#group').controlgroup().trigger('create');
});
var symbols = {
    1: 'st',
    2: 'nd',
    3: 'rd',
    4: 'th'
};
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function (e) {
    var index = $('[type=checkbox]').index($(this)) + 1;
    var symbol = index >= 4 ? symbols[4] : symbols[index];
    var str = 'This is the ' + index + symbol + ' checkbox';
    alert(str);
});
```

Hope this help.